# Hyper-V Production Checkpoint issue with Debian 11 Linux VMs

Tags: backup, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016, debian-bullseye

Just added the first Linux VM (Debian 11) to Hyper-V Server Core 2016. An error is raised while exporting VM with

```
Get-VM ... | Export-VM -CaptureLiveState CaptureDataConsistentState ...
```

The message mention an issue while creating Production Checkpoint because of VSS integration guest error 0x80004005. From what I understand hv_vss_daemon is running in the guest

```
root@...:~# ps -ef | grep hv
root          99       2  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 [hv_vmbus_con]
root         101       2  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 [hv_pri_chan]
root         102       2  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 [hv_sub_chan]
root         218       2  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 [hv_balloon]
root         245       1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/hv_kvp_daemon -n
root         397       1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/hv_fcopy_daemon -n
root         398       1  0 13:24 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/hv_vss_daemon -n
root        1927    1851  0 13:26 pts/0    00:00:00 grep hv
```

The only possible issue I can see in the host is

```
[...]: PS ...> get-vm --- | Get-VMIntegrationService |? Name -like *shadow*  | fl *

VMCheckpointId             : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
VMCheckpointName           :
Enabled                    : True
OperationalStatus          : {Ok, ProtocolMismatch}
PrimaryOperationalStatus   : Ok
PrimaryStatusDescription   : OK
SecondaryOperationalStatus : ProtocolMismatch
```

Any way to solve without reverting to normal checkpoint?

Comment: My understanding is Hyper-V Production Checkpoints use the VSS agent within the guest to create a checkpoint. Linux doesn't have VSS, so it is attempting to flush and freeze the file system. A 80004005 is a generic access denied that doesn't provide much information. Does running fsfreeze work on the guest?

Comment: "ProtocolMismatch" - that would indicate a version issue possibly? Can it be your Hyper-V is just way outdated? You are 2 major releases (2019, 2022) behind. And the integration software did change - it may simply be that either you need a more modern Hyper-V OR... that the "integration Services" need updating. Should be a package. Did you consult https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v - in particular the notes there.

Comment: @GregAskew there is a vss daemon (`/usr/sbin/hv_vss_daemon`) packaged in debian 11 and appear to be running

Comment: @TomTom yes, I had a look at that page and Windows Server 2016 seems supported and with debian 11 guests. About the ProtocolMismatch I read elsewhere about another integration service that if the primary status it's ok, the secondary status can be ignored. Not sure if this apply also to vss integration service.

Comment: @unlikely Well, it may well be something that in theory can be ignored - but it may well mean an outdated version of the installed package and that may have a fixed bug. Check your package versions.

Comment: @TomTom hyper v 2016 core host and hyper v tools under debian 11 are both up to date

Comment: I tested this with a vanilla setup of Debian 11 and Ubuntu 2004 so it's probably something specific to the configuration/capacity of your host or guest.

Comment: @GregAskew not sure what do you mean but I installed Debian 11.5 from official DVD and at the end I found the hv daemons listed. Btw, as of the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v  Debian include hv tools since version 8 .